# Callback from FireBreath

Tags: javascript, callback, npapi, firebreath

In my plugin, i want to start new thread and take callbacks from it:

I have

```
function myCallback()
```

and i want to call it every 2 seconds from my thread in plugin.

How can i do it?

```
// this method calls from html-page:
void MyFirstPluginAPI::testEvent()
{
  //fire_test();
  // thread starting:
  boost::thread my_thread(boost::bind(&MyFirstPluginAPI::hello_world, this));
}
void MyFirstPluginAPI::hello_world() 
{
  for(;;)
  {
    boost::posix_time::seconds SleepTime(2);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(SleepTime);
    // here i must call InvokeAsync("myCallback",FB::variant_list_of(0));
    // how can i to do it?
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it true answer? Is it true async callback from plugin to browser/html-page?

Maybe, i solved the problem.

I don't use **InvokeAsync**, i make 'signal':

```
FB_JSAPI_EVENT(event1, 0, ());
```

then i emit 'signal'

```
fire_event1();
```

and i receive 'signal' on site

```
addEvent(plugin(), 'event1', function(){
  elem = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + "hello<br>";
});
```

I will test this any time, and then i will mark this question as solved.

Comment: [`FB::Timer`](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class+FB+Timer) should get you there without spinning your own thread and needing to handle synchronization.

Comment: FB_JSAPI_EVENT certainly should work for what you want, and might be the way you want to do it in actuality, but you should probably also be aware that InvokeAsync can be called from any thread.

Comment: Taxilian! Thank you, but can't understand, how to use InvokeAsync. I can't find usable example. 1. How to get object, able to call InvokeAsync? 2. Why in all examples first parameter is ""? First parameter is a name of js function on site? Or no?